# WSO2 ei 6.1.1 Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers

Tags: wso2

I'm trying consume a soap web service through WSO2 ei. When invoke a web service using wso2 obtain a exception.
In WSO2, this web service is created like Proxy Service - Pass Through Service and only send inbound mnessage to endpoint address without any transformation.

But if my client invoke directly web service without wso2, it woiks fine.

This is the wso2 ei logs:

```
[2018-06-28 08:35:53,701] [EI-Core] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:65)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:177)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:155)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:108)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.doSOAPFormatConversion(Axis2Sender.java:352)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:214)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:531)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:337)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:531)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks,
José Luis

Comment: It's better to double check the 'Content-Type' header of the response. Most of the cases, if you received an HTML error message, you will notice the same exception in the ESB/EI.

Comment: How can I do the double check???

Comment: 1) Check the 'Content-Type' header when directly invoking the service.
2). Enable wire logs in the WSO2 ESB and see the messages/headers going out and coming in

Comment: Thanks. it´s that you says, HTML Error - 403 Forbidden. ESB shows error 'Content-Type' but it is caused for the HTML Error

Comment: You cannot use default XML builder and formatter to handle rich HTML content. Therefore please update axis2.xml with below message builder and formatter.

 `<messageBuilder contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/> `

Answer (score 0):

To debug this kind of issue with EI 6.1.1, you can follow the below steps:

1. Enable wire logs to capture the exact message that is being sent and received by WSO2 EI. You can enable wire logs by adding the following system property to the <EI_HOME>/conf/log4j.properties file:

   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
2. Reproduce the issue by sending the same message that caused the error. Once the error occurs, check the wire logs to see if the incoming message contains any unexpected characters or if there are any issues with the message format.

And as Chandana indicated in the comments, if it's HTML then you'll need to adjust the axis2.xml file and add in the html messagebuilder.